# ssl certificate issue in spring mvc

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, ssl-certificate

I am implementing a code that generate an error I don't understand. I'm googling since three days ago unsuccessfully. Find below my code :

**Main class**

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL("https://qosic.net:8443/QosicBridge/user/deposit");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        String json = "{\"msisdn\": \"22967307747\",\"amount\": 2000,\"transref\": 56789,\"clientid\": QOS3P001}";

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(json.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if(connection.getResponseCode() != 200){
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : Http Error code "+connection.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from server....\n");
        while((output = reader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(output);
        }       
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 19 more
```

If someone could help understanding what I did wrong, I will be very grateful

Thanks,

Comment: try to add the certificate ( export from browser ) to your jdk and it will work

Comment: I did it but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

```
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

You need to provide a keystore with a valid certificate for the host (in this case qosic.net) you are trying to connect to via https (ssl).

You can initialise your own SSL Context, see [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=javax.net.ssl.SSLContext) for examples.

Or you can ignore all certificates (WHICH IS A HACK, NOT FOR PRODUCTION) with this code

@Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {

```
    CloseableHttpClient defaultHttpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    String uri = "https://localhost/healthcheck";
    try {
        defaultHttpClient.execute(new HttpGet(uri));
        fail();
    } catch (SSLHandshakeException e) {
        // do nothing
    }

    SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
    builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
            return true;
        }
    });
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build());

    CloseableHttpClient customHttpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory).build();
    CloseableHttpResponse response = customHttpClient.execute(new HttpGet(uri));
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}
```